# Returned class is null when constructor argument is a reference while using reflection php

Tags: php, reflection, reference

I have 2 classes MyClass and MyClass2. I need to call a new instance of MyClass using reflection, passing to the constructor an instance of MyClass2. This works fine until I try using the reference in MyClass2 constructor, `$classObject` in this case will be null.

Why is this problem occurring? Knowing that this does not happen while testing a similar function call between two function within the same class without reflection!!

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$args = array(new MyClass2());
$classReflection = new ReflectionClass($className);   
$classObject = $classReflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

**MyClass**

```
public function __construct(&$myClass2)
```

Comment: `classReflection` is missing its dollar sign in the final line of your first code block. Is that just a typo?

Comment: yeah @Simon, this is a typo here in this question, not the main problem

Comment: Does it have to be a reference in the first place? There's no need to do that if you're passing an object. The only reasonable reason to worry about this is if `MyClass` is legacy 3rd party code you can't touch…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward solution is to modify `MyClass`'s constructor so it no longer requires a reference:

```
public function __construct($myClass2) { }
```

As deceze notes in his comment above, there's generally no need to pass objects by reference; [they are always passed by object identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), which functions as a pointer and ensures all variables to which an object is assigned operate directly on that object's data.

However, your example illustrates some unusual behaviour in PHP. Like [vuliad says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673104/473305), your code as written fails on PHP 7 with this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Parameter 1 to MyClass::__construct() expected to be a reference, value given
```

This is surprising, because [the PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign),

> Since PHP 5, `new` returns a reference automatically...

So `$args` *should* hold an array that contains a reference, as `MyClass`'s constructor expects. But the only way I can get your original code to work is by first assigning the new instance of `MyClass2` to a variable, like this:

```
$newClass2 = new MyClass2();
$args = array(&$newClass2);

$classReflection = new ReflectionClass($className);   
$classObject = $classReflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

This is a solution, too. But again, passing objects by reference is unnecessary, so I recommend simply changing the `MyClass` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via arguments unpacking:

```
$classObject = new $className(...$args);
```

This is really interesting case, for php7.0+ we can see Error:

> Warning: Parameter 1 to MyClass::__construct() expected to be a reference, value given in /in/Bgjlj on line 15

try here https://3v4l.org/Bgjlj